# Maximum Number of Tasks can be launched in one MPI application

Tags: int, mpi, communicator

In the C binding, MPI_Comm_size returns an `int` type value. the maximum value of `int` in C is 32767. Does it mean at most 32K processes can be created in a communicator? But this seems too small since I know there are applications that can run on millions of cores. What I have missed?

Comment: Not sure what MPI is, but int isn't necessarily 16-bit, and today usually it is 32-bit or 64-bit.  What does the following tell you: `printf("%d",sizeof(int));`?

Comment: Those applications that you *know* of that run on millions of cores -- whose marketing literature have you been reading uncritically ?  Or, what have you been smoking ?

Comment: I have run on hundreds of thousands of cores, but I am using Fortran, and the MPI Interface provides a default integer, which happens to be a signed 32 bit integer, and could support up to 2 billion processes...

Comment: @RobertMcKee `sizeof(int)` is 32-bit. I read the detail of the C datatype specs, it says the range of `int` is at least [-132767,32767]. I think 'at least' is a keyword here. So if `int` is 32-bit long, its range should be much larger.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Please google "running mpi on millions of cores".

Comment: Then on the system you are running on, it will likely support up to 2 billion processes. (32-bit ints have a range of (approximately) +-2147483647).  In C, ints don't have a specific size and varies based on the compiler used and the target system.  I never liked that definition and found it rather useless myself.  The newer C99 integer types (int32_t) makes much more sense for any work I have ever done.

Answer (score 1):

From the POSIX man page of `limits.h`:

> ```
>    {INT_MAX}
>           Maximum value of an int.
>           Minimum Acceptable Value: 2 147 483 647
> ```

The *minimum* of the maximum `int` is like thousands of millions (2^31 - 1).